# What is the best resource for BlackBerry CLDC programming?

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, cldc

I deployed many midlets on Blackberry, but now I want to try their CLDC model. Never deal with it. What is the best resource to read for a quick start (except the BB examples?)

Comment: Is there a reason that the examples are not an acceptable resource?

Comment: They are, I am just looking for something additional, I never used this model / UI before. Is the UI closed / based on AWT (or Swing), or AWT books will not help?

Answer (score 1):

This site has a great series of articles on how to build a real-word blackberry app

[How to Build a Real-World BlackBerry Application](http://www.miamicoder.com/post/2008/04/How-To-Build-a-Real-World-BlackBerry-Application.aspx)

While not a quick read these two forms have helped me quite a bit:

[Blackberry Support Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/?category.id=BlackBerryDevelopment)

[Blackberry Forums](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/)

Here are some other resources I have found helpful:

[Getting started with the Blackberry Java Development Environment (JDE)](http://devsushi.com/2007/11/15/getting-started-with-the-blackberry-java-development-environment-jde/)

[Develop applications for the BlackBerry](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5265422.html)

[jonathanhfisher's Blog](http://www.jonathanhfisher.co.uk/b2/?cat=2)